# Django db query not behaving the same way in views.py and shell

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-shell

I am trying to generate a query for which I get the expected result in django shell, but for the same query, I am getting an error that the attribute for the model does not exist.

First the shell:

```
>>> from dbaccess.models import *
>>> applicantObject = Applicant.objects.get(pk=5)
>>> vol = VolInterview.objects.get(applicant=applicantObject)
>>> vol
<VolInterview: Rajon>
```

From views.py

```
from models import *

def addIntCandidate(request):
    applicants = Applicant.objects.filter(applicationStatus="Pending")
    interviews = Interview.objects.all()
    message = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        applicant = request.POST.get('applicant')
        ...
        # the value of applicant at this point is 5
        applicantObject = Applicant.objects.get(pk=applicant)
        prevRejected = VolInterview.objects.get(applicant=applicantObject)
        ...
```

Error message:

```
type object 'VolInterview' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Traceback:

```
E:\projects_directory\djangoprojects\kpr-admin-db\dbaccess\views.py in addIntCandidate
                    prevRejected = VolInterview.objects.get(applicant=applicantObject)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you have replaced `VolInterview` with a different class in your views.py? To check, add `print(VolInterview)` to your view and the shell, and check that you get the same result.

Comment: I actually imported another form with the same name. Thanks for pointing out.

Could you post in the answer section, so that I could accept it?

Comment: @Alasdair, could me guide me to how I could combine both the queries into a single one? -> applicantObject = Applicant.objects.get(pk=applicant) and prevRejected = VolInterview.objects.get(applicant=applicantObject)

Comment: **NEVER** use star imports (`from module import *`) in your code - this "feature" should only be used in a Python shell.

Comment: @roy: `prevRejected = VolInterview.objects.get(applicant__pk=applicant)` (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships),  though in this case you can just use `VolInterview.objects.get(applicant=applicant)`. But please post new questions as new questions, not as (totally unrelated) comment on this question.

Comment: `.get(applicant_id=applicant)` might be even better.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thanks for tip. I just thought since I was going to use all the class definitions, I went for the *. But now I can see how that could go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have replaced `VolInterview` with a different class in your views.

To check, you can add `print(VolInterview)` to your view and the shell, and check that you get the same result in both.

In Django, it is common to use `Form` as a suffix for your form classes, e.g. `VolInterviewForm`, so that the model and form names do not clash.